# Oracle on windows cluster with online/offline IPs

Tags: windows-server-2008, oracle, failover, oracle10g, windows-cluster

I have a windows cluster (on windows 2008 server) with nodes in different subnets. So cluster has two IPs, one for each node (I'm talking not about node IP, but about cluster IP). One is online, the other is offline.

Is it possible to run Oracle Fail Safe on this configuration? I've tried to install it, but it gives me the following error when trying to verify group or add database to group:

FS-10220: Network name  maps to IP address  in the cluster resource but maps to IP address  on the system

Answer (score 0):

This is Bug 7606294 "Unable To Add Database To Fail Safe Group 3.4.1" DocId: 799024.1

To solve this problem, use the latest version of Oracle Fail Safe. And install patches for Oracle Fail Safe, downloaded from Oracle Support (Metalink).

P.S. Failsafe is only High Availability solution, but "Data guard" is disaster recovery solution. "Real Application Cluster" is High Availability + Scalability.

Comment: I had the last version of the ofs 3.4.2 and oracle 10.2.0.4 SE.

i've recieved a replay from support:

they said the cluster can only have one ip.